# What is the correct procedure for installing the Snowflake Python API

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to use Python to interact with my Snowflake account. To get started I am following the [Getting started with the Snowflake Python API](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting-started-snowflake-python-api/index.html#1) quickstart which clearly states to run the following commands:

```bash
python3 -m venv '.venv'
source '.venv/bin/activate'
pip install snowflake
```

Well I tried that then subsequently attempted to run the simplest of code, `from snowflake.core import Root` which I took from [page 3 of the quickstart](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting-started-snowflake-python-api/index.html#2). It failed:

```
➜  ~ cd /tmp
➜  /tmp mkdir test-snowflake
➜  /tmp cd test-snowflake
➜  test-snowflake python -m venv .venv && \
  python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
  source .venv/bin/activate
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/jamiethomson/.pyenv/versions/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.3.2)
(.venv) ➜  test-snowflake pip install snowflake
Collecting snowflake
  Using cached snowflake-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.4 kB)
Collecting snowflake-core==0.5.1
  Using cached snowflake_core-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (323 kB)
Collecting snowflake
  Using cached snowflake-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 kB)
Collecting snowflake-core==0.5.0
  Using cached snowflake_core-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (323 kB)
Collecting snowflake
  Using cached snowflake-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 kB)
Collecting snowflake-core==0.4.0
  Using cached snowflake_core-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (323 kB)
Collecting snowflake
  Using cached snowflake-0.0.4.tar.gz (2.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: snowflake
  DEPRECATION: snowflake is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for snowflake ... done
Successfully installed snowflake-0.0.4

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(.venv) ➜  test-snowflake python -c "from snowflake.core import Root"
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: This package has been renamed to snowflake_uuid and will be removed shortly. Please update immediately.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.core'; 'snowflake' is not a package
```

Screenshot to prove it:

[image: Screenshot of commands and output]

I have followed the commands exactly but they did not behave as advertised. I am assuming that this quickstart is out-of-date however it is linked to from the API documentation: [Snowflake documentation > Developer > Snowflake Python API: Managing Snowflake objects with Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/snowflake-python-overview)

I don't know what is wrong here. Can someone tell me the correct steps for using Snowflake's python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out why this wasn't working, I was using python 3.11.2 and one of the dependencies isn't yet supported on 3.11.2. To prove it:

```bash
pyenv local 3.11 && \
  python3 -m venv '.venv' && \
  source .venv/bin/activate && \\
  pip install snowflake
<snip>
Successfully installed snowflake-0.0.4
```

```bash
pyenv local 3.10 && \
  python3 -m venv '.venv' && \
  source .venv/bin/activate && \
  pip install snowflake
<snip>
Successfully installed asn1crypto-1.5.1 atpublic-4.0 certifi-2023.11.17 cffi-1.16.0 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 cloudpickle-2.2.1 cryptography-41.0.7 filelock-3.13.1 idna-3.6 packaging-23.2 platformdirs-3.11.0 pyOpenSSL-23.3.0 pycparser-2.21 pydantic-1.10.14 pyjwt-2.8.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2023.3.post1 pyyaml-6.0.1 requests-2.31.0 six-1.16.0 snowflake-0.5.1 snowflake-connector-python-3.6.0 snowflake-core-0.5.1 snowflake-legacy-0.4.0 snowflake-snowpark-python-1.11.1 sortedcontainers-2.4.0 tomlkit-0.12.3 typing-extensions-4.9.0 urllib3-2.1.0 wheel-0.42.0
```

Once I changed the version of python I was able to do what I needed, which in this case was to query the state of a warehouse. Here's the code in case it helps anyone:

```py
import os
from snowflake.connector import connect
from snowflake.core import Root

CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {
    "account": os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT"),
    "user": os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_USER"),
    "authenticator": "externalbrowser"
}

# run using
# SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=account.region SNOWFLAKE_USER=FIRST.LAST@COMPANY.COM python script.py
conn = connect(**CONNECTION_PARAMETERS)
root = Root(conn)
wh = root.warehouses["WAREHOUSE_NAME"].fetch()
print(wh.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems the documentation is indeed out of date. CoPilot was able to tell me that the package I needed to install is snowflake-connector-python</strike>

[![copilot conversation][1]][1]

Once I pip installed that I was able to establish a connection

Thanks to a comment on this answer I realised that my previous answer here was incorrect. The snowflake-connector-python is a different package that has different motivations. At the time of writing I still maintain that the documentation for the Snowflake Python API is incorrect, as I said above.

Comment: Interestingly I searched for the same on Google https://www.google.com/search?q=What+package+do+I+need+to+pip+install+in+order+to+use+the+snowflake+python+api&sca_esv=599760920&sxsrf=ACQVn09XdB-hujtLJo36-O3YWJ-lh6jDFg%3A1705661346772&source=hp&ei=olOqZcOhLZyZhbIPtr2i-Ak&iflsig=ANes7DEAAAAAZaphsm22ZztnQl-aqSOTDnDPJZJstC44&ved=0ahUKEwjD-rfVo-mDAxWcTEEAHbaeCJ8Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=What+package+do+I+need+to+pip+install+in+order+to+use+the+snowflake+python+api. Top hit was the erroneous documentation I linked to in the question above. 1 up for copilot.

Comment: Snowflake Python connector and Python API are two different features/packages. First one more oriented to work with the data, while the second one to work with the account resources. The correct way to install Python API is described in the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/snowflake-python-installing) This is relatively new feature and copilot might be simply not aware that it exists. Snowflake Python Connector has been around for a while.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, good info. I have already looked at the doc you linked to however perhaps I missed something. I'll look again.

Comment: And, FYI, "working with the account resources" is exactly what I'd like to do as opposed to working with data in the account.

Comment: OK, I've done a bit more reading. The tutorial that I linked to in the first message in this thread is indeed referring to the Python API (as opposed to the Snowflake Python Connector) however I maintain that it does not behave as advertised, for the reasons I already gave.

Comment: I’ve updated this answer accordingly. Thanks Alexander.